# Splicing last names with infixes

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got users who've got infixes in their last name like `Es`, `Van Zaal` and `Van der Dijk`.

I'm trying to get the last names in three columns.
`lastname`, `without_infix`, `infix`

Using

```
IF(lastname = SUBSTRING_INDEX(lastname, ' ', -1), NULL, SUBSTRING_INDEX(lastname, ' ', -1))
```

I can manage to get both `Es`, `Van Zaal` correctly. With this however I don't get the `der` from `Van der Dijk`.

**Example:**

If I have lastnames `Es`, `Van Zaal` and `Van der Dijk`

The result should be
[image: example result]

How can I get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
select lastname,
       substring_index(lastname, ' ', -1) as without_prefix,
       left(lastname, length(lastname) - length(substring_index(lastname, ' ', -1))) as prefix
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=336a03eaf45cc812e86458ff481fd965) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Works almost perfectly. The only thing missing is that it should be set to NULL if there is no infix. But I can check this by putting an `IF` statement around it.